# Excludes for Cx Freeze Builds

Tags: python, build-process, cx-freeze

I have a question regarding building distribution files using CX Freeze.

I have built several distribution packages for different set of codes and application that I have written in Python.

I usually use Cx_Freeze to make my build and distribution packages.

One of the key target most of the time will be the size of the package before and after installation.

Although Cx_freeze picks up the necessary module, most of the time you end up adding certain libraries such matplotlib backends, numpy library etc when you use them as a part of your code.

The Key trick to reduce the size could be excluding the modules that you don't need as part of your code.

Most of the time for me it will be trial and error.

But how one could decide the most optimized build with stripping all non essential modules during the build?

Say for example if my application is not GUI based, I end up removing tkinter, but once matplotlib backend was using and I had to bring it back again.

Is it always iterative process?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you exclude something and then later need that, then yes, you will need to remove it from excludes.

Comment: Hi Thomas Thanks for your reply. No My point is how will determine what is not needed during a build. What are all the modules that Cx_freeze builds by default? How can i optimise the size of builds.

Comment: cx_Freeze scans your code for imports and copies those modules, so normally it will only copy the things that you need. But something like matplotlib is tricky, because it has multiple backends, which you normally only use one of, but cx_Freeze can't easily see which one your program will be using.